# Problem including graphic into hugo website

Tags: hugo, ggplotly, hugo-shortcode

I am desperately trying to include a graphic made with r (but in HTML format) in a markdown page (hugo website) and unfortunately I don't understand the logic or I am doing something wrong...
Any help would be welcome thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with R graphics - but typical markdown image in hugo should be the following syntax: ![Alt](/path/goes/here.jpg "Title") - that's markdown. Of course that's expecting an image. Markdown, IF the goldmark renderer is set to render HTML, does support raw HTML, so you could just maybe, embed the ggplotly output directly. Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us what of https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#figure does not work?

It should work with the figure shortcode.

Comment: I insert the following code but nothing happen ?<figure>
  <img src="static/images/graphic.html" alt="my graphic">
</figure>

Comment: I also try :      {{< figure src="/images/graphic.html" >}} still doesn't display ?

Comment: Ah, now I get it, your graphic is a html page. Please have a look inside the HTML, there are two options: 1) it already has an <img> tag in it, then use that src instead, if it has a <svg> inside, save the svg part as an .svg file and reference that. Or maybe even easier: convert your graphic to a png or svg and include it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the HTML in a file (yourhtmlfile.html) in the shortcodes directory (in the layouts folder) and call that shortcode in your content like this:

```
{{< yourhtmlfile >}}
```